# Format a knockout value using custom binding

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to perform a two-way conversion on a knockout observable when it is bound to an HTML input element.  More specifically, I want to replace "<BR>" strings with "\n" characters when copying to the input and replace "\n" characters with "<BR>" strings when copied back to the model.  In other words, I have the following two requirements:

1. When the value is copied from knockout observable it should go through one conversion.
2. When the value in the input is changed and it is copied back to the knockout observable, it should go through a reverse conversion.

Since I'm using knockout.mapping, I don't want to use .extend(), and I'd rather use a custom bindingHandler.

I've found lots of examples where you can format an observable into a read only element like a DIV.
And I've found lots of other examples where you can modify the value that is entered into the input.
But none of these work quite right for me.  Everything I've tried always results in the conversion just working one way or another, but not both ways sucessfully.

Here's my most recent attempt:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlToTextValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var interceptor = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                var valueObservable = valueAccessor();
                var value = valueObservable();
                var textValue = String(value)
                    .replace(/\<br\>/g, "\n")
                    .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
                    .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
                    .replace(/&#39;/g, "'")
                    .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
                    .replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
                return textValue;
            },
            write: function (value) {
                var valueObservable = valueAccessor();
                var htmlValue = String(value)
                    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                    .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                    .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
                    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                    .replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
                valueObservable(htmlValue);
            }
            ,disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: interceptor }, context);
    }
};
```

And here's it's use:

```
<input type="textarea" data-bind="htmlToTextValue: Value" />
```

Comment: Can you try to create a small demo in jsfiddle/jsbin? Also have you tried with textarea? So with `<textarea data-bind="htmlToTextValue: Value" ></textarea>`

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9e7u1tr/1/), though it's late and I can't seem to figure out why the *initial state* isn't shown. (Type in the textarea to see things at work...)

Comment: @Jeroen your example works great, but that doesn't work in my own code.  I'm running Knockout version 3.1.0, whereas jsfiddle has 3.0.0.  I read that the newer version of knockout ignores calls to ko.bindingHandlers.value.init.  I wonder if that's true or if that's why.

Comment: @Jeroen: actually, it looks like MVC Control Toolkit was inserting an extra binding onto my textarea, which was the real issue.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JoshMouch good to hear you solved it! Could you add some details on your solution as an answer? Perhaps others are experiencing a similar issue, and they may find use in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

it's not working because you're only setting up the init function, so it won't respond to any updates. Try adding the update option to the handler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlToTextValue = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        // your code
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying I should copy the init code to the update method, as well?  That doesn't seem quite right, since I'm calling ko.applyBindingsToNode.

Comment: Essentially, the init allows you to bind the value from the observable and the update allows you to map the value in the element back to the observed object/value.  I do it this way for date pickers. The init and update are optional depending on whether you want one way bindings or two-way bindings.  I have some with just inits, some with updates and some with both.

Comment: @JoshMouch you shouldn't call applyBindings from it, but update element node contents instead. Here is a sample: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working solution for a two-way binding between text and HTML:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.htmlToTextValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, context) {
        var interceptor = ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                var valueObservable = valueAccessor();
                var value = valueObservable();
                var textValue = String(value)
                    .replace(/<br>/gi, "\n")
                    .replace(/&gt;/gi, '>')
                    .replace(/&lt;/gi, '<')
                    .replace(/&#39;/gi, "'")
                    .replace(/&quot;/gi, '"')
                    .replace(/&amp;/gi, '&');
                return textValue;
            },
            write: function (value) {
                var valueObservable = valueAccessor();
                var htmlValue = String(value)
                    .replace(/&/gi, '&amp;')
                    .replace(/"/gi, '&quot;')
                    .replace(/'/gi, '&#39;')
                    .replace(/</gi, '&lt;')
                    .replace(/>/gi, '&gt;')
                    .replace(/\n/gi, "<br>");
                valueObservable(htmlValue);
            }
        });

        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { value: interceptor }, context);
    }
};
```